# Page source data in not set to first record in ng2-smart-table.

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

In my `ngOnInit()` I have called the API in that API I got list of data. E.x : 26 data.

```
for (let i = 0; i < getUsersResponse.data.length; i++) {
   let data = {
       // ... I have set data based on my table which is works fine.
   }
   this.usersDataSource.append(data)
}
```

After append all data in source I want to dislay data from scratch. So for that I have set page.

```
this.usersDataSource.setPage(1);
this.usersDataSource.refresh();
```

Still I got last data range. I got data from 21 to 26 at first time. I don't know why it is not updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/493), *setPage* doesn't work well; so you should use *setPaging* like this (for a pagesize of 20 items):

```
this.usersDataSource.setPaging(1, 20, true);
```

You don't need to call the *refresh* method because with the third argument set to *true* the refresh is automatic.

You could also try to use

```
this.usersDataSource.add(data);
```

instead of the *append* function. The append function sets the current page to the last; but the *add* function doesn't ([watch this](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation))

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried but not works for me! :(

Comment: Have you tried to use the *add* function instead of the *append*? this function doesn't change the current page to the last

Comment: It solves my issue by set `add()` instead of `append()`.